# Google style drop down - Content bigger than parent

Tags: html, css

This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/dv6gxtoh/2/

I want the dropdown box to expand and be the full width of it's content (so it doesn't have to drop things down a line) but I also don't want it to stretch the main dropdown button to the same width.

The best example I can give is something a bit like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ym8.png

This is the CSS I am using:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.click-nav ul {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.click-nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
.click-nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker {
    position:relative;
    color:black;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover, .click-nav ul .active {
    background:#196F9A;
}
.click-nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px 10px;
    background:#FFF;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {
    background:#F2F2F2;
}
/* Fallbacks */
 .click-nav .no-js ul {
    display:none;
}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

The closest I could get it to remove `position:relative;` from `.click-nav ul` which does the trick, except the dropdown menu doesn't sit under the button which opened it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me `white-space : nowrap` is what you need, i.e

```css
.click-nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px 10px;
    background:#FFF;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j5ckepbm/**

Answer (score 1):

Check the shared fiddle..

you need to make few changes to your css, like adding  and width/min-width to your dropdown.

```
white-space:nowrap
```

[Click to see the fiddle, commented lines are mine changes](https://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/dv6gxtoh/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add one more class with a fixed width to get it done.

```
.click-nav ul li ul li {
    width: 150px;
}
```

**Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv6gxtoh/10/)**